# Rackspace Cloud Server DNS Add SPF Records

Tags: domain-name-system, rackspace-cloud, spf

I've setup my new LAMP server on Rackspace Cloud and the Basic `A`, `C` and `MX` DNS setup is no problem.

I need to add an `SPF` record for a project I am migrating over to this new server that allows emails from a 3rd party server and I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

There doesn't seem to be an option to add a `TXT` record in my Rackspace Cloud Server interface and I installed the BIND DNS on my Apache server, but I am not sure how to get that to been seen, etc.

Comment: So which do you want to do?  Run your own DNS server, or contact Rackspace support to ask them for TXT record support in their excruciatingly painful DNS management webapp?

Comment: well if you put it that way, run my own dns.

Comment: Have you contacted rackspace support yet? If not, why haven't you?!

Comment: Hell, the whole point of Rackspace is the support, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Rackspace is making efforts to improve the control panel but in the meantime, you can use the newly announced DNS API to add TXT/SPF records. Check out the Rackspace [blog post](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/blog/2011/07/07/rackspace-cloud-dns-beta-now-available-for-us-uk-cloud-customers/).

I also wrote a [tutorial on using curl to use the API](http://www.collazo.ws/2011/07/08/using-rackspace-dnsaas-with-curl-part-1).